# HTML 5 Canvas input is overridden

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So, I manage to make the input code for my project

```
function showText(stringTuts,stringKey)  //this is the class for showing the text
{
ctx.font = "20px Arial";
ctx.fillText(stringTuts,503,150);
ctx.fillText(stringKey,713,150);
}

window.addEventListener("keypress",onKeyPress);
function onKeyPress(e)
{
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    var str = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    console.log(str+":"+e.keyCode);
    var tune = new Audio();


    if (e.keyCode == 113)  //this code is for the input
    {

        tune = new Audio("Assets/Tune/C.mp3"); //play the sound when key is pressed
        tune.play();
        stringTuts = "C";
        stringKey = "Q";
        showText(stringTuts,stringKey); //showing the text what key is being pressed right now

    }
    else if ( e.keyCode == 119)
    {

        tune = new Audio("Assets/Tune/D.mp3");
        tune.play();
        stringTuts = "D";
        stringKey = "W";
        showText(stringTuts,stringKey);
    }
    else if ( e.keyCode == 101)
    {
        tune = new Audio("Assets/Tune/E.mp3");
        tune.play();
        stringTuts = "E";
        stringKey = "E";
        showText(stringTuts,stringKey);
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 114)
    {
        tune = new Audio("Assets/Tune/F.mp3");
        tune.play();
        stringTuts = "F";
        stringKey = "R";
        showText(stringTuts,stringKey);
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 116)
    {
        tune = new Audio("Assets/Tune/G.mp3");
        tune.play();
        stringTuts = "G";
        stringKey = "T";
        showText(stringTuts,stringKey);
    }
}
```

my problem is that when I successfully press the 'Q' button, the showText() function can show what key is being pressed, but if I pressed 'W', it will show the key without deleting the 'Q' button text. I've tried some ways like making temp variable in onKeyPress(e) function but it doesnt help at all. Can someone help me figure how to fix this ? Thanks

Comment: You have to clear your canvas using [clearRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect)

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are not clearing the canvas before adding new text to it. Just add `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, widthOfCanvas, heightOfCanvas);` to the beginning of the `showText()` function.

Additional information on the `ctx.clearRect` function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect

Comment: thanks it fix the case, I have tried to add clearRect() before, but it seemed I put it in wrong way.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help. **EDIT**: By the way, you may want to consider accepting this answer if it was correct so others can find it in the future.